# appending element contents with the contents of a descendant elements sibling with jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-traversing

I have the following html...

```
<body>
    <section>
        <div class="clip">
            <header>first section header</header>
            <aside>first section aside</aside>           
        </div>
        <article>
            <div class="content">
            </div>
        </article>
        <article>
            <div class="content">
            </div>
        </article>
    </section>
    <section>
        <div class="clip">
            <header>second section header</header>
            <aside>second section aside</aside>           
        </div>
        <article>
            <div class="content">
            </div>
        </article>
        <article>
            <div class="content">
            </div>
        </article>
    </section>
</body>
```

Using jQuery I want to append all the .content divs with the contents of their descendant sections .clip div.

forming this...

```
<body>
    <section>
        <div class="clip">
            <header>first section header</header>
            <aside>first section aside</aside>           
        </div>
        <article>
            <div class="content">
                <header>first section header</header>
                <aside>first section aside</aside>
            </div>
        </article>
        <article>
            <div class="content">
                <header>first section header</header>
                <aside>first section aside</aside>                
            </div>
        </article>
    </section>
    <section>
        <div class="clip">
            <header>second section header</header>
            <aside>second section aside</aside>           
        </div>
        <article>
            <div class="content">
                <header>second section header</header>
                <aside>second section aside</aside> 
            </div>
        </article>
        <article>
            <div class="content">
                <header>second section header</header>
                <aside>second section aside</aside> 
            </div>
        </article>
    </section>
</body>
```

currently I have this for the jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".content").prepend($(".content").parentsUntil("section").siblings("div").html());
});
```

which only selects the documents first .clip divs contents. How do I form the selector/jquery line to use the proper .clip divs for each .content div?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `each` to loop through the clips, and then duplicate their HTML into all `content` elements within the same `section:

```
$(".clip").each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.closest("section").find(".content").append($this.html());
});
```

**Live example**:

```js
$(".clip").each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.closest("section").find(".content").append($this.html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
        <div class="clip">
            <header>first section header</header>
            <aside>first section aside</aside>           
        </div>
        <article>
            <div class="content">
            </div>
        </article>
        <article>
            <div class="content">
            </div>
        </article>
    </section>
    <section>
        <div class="clip">
            <header>second section header</header>
            <aside>second section aside</aside>           
        </div>
        <article>
            <div class="content">
            </div>
        </article>
        <article>
            <div class="content">
            </div>
        </article>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('section').each(function() { // Loop through each section
    var content = $(this).find('.clip').html(); // Get the inner html of .clip div inside this
    $(this).find('.content').prepend(content); // Add the contents for each .content div found inside this section
}
```

It will also work if you change your entire html markup, as soon as you leave the class names unchanged....

Answer (score 0):

You could use callback to **[`.html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html/)** to append inner Html of `.clip` and get it by using `closest()`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".content").html(function(){
        return $(this).closest('section').find('.clip').html()
    });
});
```

**[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7yjv7akh/)**